# Position of sprite icons in CSS

Tags: html, css, sprite, css-sprites

[image: sprite image]

This is my sprite image, the icons are  64*64 (total 64*384) in dimension. I'm trying to display the icons but only one/the first one works. I am new to this CSS Sprite thing. So looking for help/guide.

```css
#Accommodation {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4dZe.png") 0 0;
 border: 0px none;
}

#Activities {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4dZe.png") 0 -64;
 border: 0px none;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="included[]" name="included[]" value="Accommodation"> <img id="Accommodation" src="img/trans.png" />Accommodation </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="included[]" name="included[]" value="Activities"> <img id="Activities" src="img/trans.png" /> Activities </label>
```

*The transparent image is not added here, you can ignore that part.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly set units for non-zero values in CSS, so `-64` should be `-64px` in your case:

```css
#Accommodation {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4dZe.png") 0 0;
 border: 0px none;
}

#Activities {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4dZe.png") 0 -64px;
 border: 0px none;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="included[]" name="included[]" value="Accommodation"> <img id="Accommodation" src="img/trans.png" />Accommodation </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="included[]" name="included[]" value="Activities"> <img id="Activities" src="img/trans.png" /> Activities </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get sprite icon position:- http://www.spritecow.com/

Just Example:-

```
.sprite{background: url("img/sprite.png"); display:inline-block; line-height:0;}
.activities{background-position:0 0; width: 64px; height: 64px;}

<div class="sprite activities"></div>
```

This best way for multiple uses.